# Как изменить ширину MDDialog?

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton, MDRaisedButton
class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        bl=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', height='50dp',width=100, spacing='10dp')
        bl.add_widget(MDTextField(hint_text="79876543210", max_text_length= 11))
        dialog = MDDialog(title='Авторизация',radius=[20, 7, 20, 7], content_cls=bl, type='custom',
            buttons=[MDFlatButton(text='Отмена', text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color),
            MDRaisedButton(text='Подтвердить', text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color)])
        dialog.open()
Example().run()
```

Есть такой код, как поменять ширину диалога? Пытался задать в боксе, но бесполезно, у самого диалога никаких параметров ширины нет, если я его не пропустил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Элементарно. Используйте свойство `size_hint_x`:

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton, MDRaisedButton


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        bl = BoxLayout(
            orientation="vertical", height="50dp", width=100, spacing="10dp"
        )
        bl.add_widget(MDTextField(hint_text="79876543210", max_text_length=11))
        dialog = MDDialog(
            title="Авторизация",
            radius=[20, 7, 20, 7],
            content_cls=bl,
            type="custom",
            size_hint_x=0.9,
            buttons=[
                MDFlatButton(
                    text="Отмена", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color
                ),
                MDRaisedButton(
                    text="Подтвердить", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color
                ),
            ],
        )
        dialog.open()


Example().run()
```